# MATLAB: Format Character Array Output Back to the Declared Variables

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, if-statement

This character array uses a for loop to index through the (basketArray) data, uses IF to check for subscript (00) in data, and if true deletes the (00) subscript.  This is achieved with the output of:

```
rmsubscript = applesorangespineapplespinachbroccoliturnips.
```

Next step is where I am having the problem: how do I get the character array output back into its declared x and y containers, formatted by a column and separated as:

x =

```
apples
oranges
pineapple
```

y =

```
 spinach
 broccoli
 turnips
```

Here is my code:

```
x = ['00apples', 'oranges', '00pineapple']
y = ['00spinach', 'broccoli', '00turnips']

basketArray = [x, y]
pattern = '00';
subscript = contains(basketArray, pattern);
for k = basketArray
    if subscript == contains(basketArray, pattern);
            rmsubscript = regexprep(basketArray, '00', ''),                                                    
    end
end
```

Comment: Realistically, you don't, because concatenating them together into character vectors is destructive (and unnecessary). Store your words in cell arrays, `regexprep` works on them natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [string arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) or [cell arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) to contain your words. Note that `x` and `y` are probably not what you're expecting:

```
x =

    '00applesoranges00pineapple'

y =

    '00spinachbroccoli00turnips'
```

`regexprep` works natively on both cell and string arrays:

```
x = {'00apples', 'oranges', '00pineapple'};
y = {'00spinach', 'broccoli', '00turnips'};

basket = [x; y];
new_basket = regexprep(basket, '00', '')
```

and

```
x = ["00apples", "oranges", "00pineapple"];
y = ["00spinach", "broccoli", "00turnips"];

basket = [x; y];
new_basket = regexprep(basket, '00', '')
```

Both produce the desired result:

```
new_basket = 

  2×3 string array

    "apples"     "oranges"     "pineapple"
    "spinach"    "broccoli"    "turnips"
```